# Why does pgfpages not allow plain text in a beamer column environment?

Tags: beamer, xetex, columns

Using XeLatex and beamer class, I want to make a presentation with notes. The pgfpages package does this nicely. But when I make a column environment AND want the notes produced, then text will not appear although itemize items will. This seems weird!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
% Beamer Setup
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

%%%%%%% notes 
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
%\setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=left} % Both

\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    testing 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
        stuff
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
        content...stuff here too
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
            \begin{itemize}
            \item stuff here
            \item and here
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
        but stuff only appears here when you are not showing notes
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: That's a known problem with xelatex. See https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Lualatex which allowed me to keep the pretty font but get around this but in xelatex.